# Display values from array 2D inside table C#

Tags: c#, arrays

I am new at programming in C# and I'm trying to create a method that allows me to create a table and visualize the data inside of a matrix. However none of the methods I have tried seems to work as supposed.

Basically the method works to visualize the header which is the Enum, however I need to read the data from the matrix and the output has to be in the form of a table. Here´s the code so far:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApp3
{
    enum clientHeader { Id, Name, Surname, Addres, Cod_Postal, Telephone, Email, State };

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string[,] client = new string[3, 7];

            insertData<clientHeader>(client);
            Console.Clear();
            showHeader<clientHeader>(client);

            listData<clientHeader>(client); 

            Console.ReadKey();
        }

       static void insertData<T>(string[,] matrix)
       {
            int x = matrix.GetLowerBound(1);
            matrix[0, x] = "1";

            for (int j = 1; j < matrix.GetLength(1); j++)
            {
                do
                {
                    Console.Write($"\nInsert {GetHeader<T>(j)}: ");
                    matrix[0, j] = Console.ReadLine();
                } while (String.IsNullOrEmpty(matrix[0, j]));
            }
        }

        static void listData<T>(string[,] matrix)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < matrix.GetLength(0); i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < matrix.GetLength(1); j++)
                {
                    Console.Write($"{matrix[i, j]}\t");
                }
            }

            Console.WriteLine();
        }
    }

    private static string GetHeader<T>(int i) => Enum.GetName(typeof(T), i);

        static void showHeader<T>(string[,] matrix)
        {
            int x = matrix.GetUpperBound(1);
            string[] array = new string[x];

            for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
            {
                array[i] = GetHeader<T>(i);
            }

            PrintLine();
            PrintRow(array);
            PrintLine();
        }

        static int tableWidth = 120;

        static void PrintLine()
        {
            Console.WriteLine(new string('-', tableWidth));
        }

        static void PrintRow(params string[] columns)
        {
            int width = (tableWidth - columns.Length) / columns.Length;
            string row = "|";

            foreach (string column in columns)
            {
                row += AlignCentre(column, width) + "|";
            }

            Console.WriteLine(row);
        }

        static string AlignCentre(string text, int width)
        {
            text = text.Length > width ? text.Substring(0, width - 3) + "..." : text;

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(text))
            {
                return new string(' ', width);
            }
            else
            {
                return text.PadRight(width - (width - text.Length) / 2).PadLeft(width);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The code on the main (ListData) is supossed to read the matrix and display it such the Enum is being shown as output

Comment: This question is too broad - please edit it and ask a specific question. What is the output you're expecting, what are you seeing instead, and what part of the code is problematic. *"none of the methods I have tried seems to work as supposed"* does not tell us what the problem is.

Comment: the method ListData<T>(string[,] matrix) was meant to read multiples lines from a large matrix

Answer (score 2):

In the code below, the main modification I made was to have your `ListData` method act like your `ShowHeader` method, so that the data is aligned in columns underneath the header:

```
private static void ListData<T>(string[,] matrix)
{
    var array = new string[matrix.GetUpperBound(1)];

    for (var i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
    {
        array[i] = matrix[0, i];
    }

    PrintRow(array);
    PrintLine();
}
```

See if that works for you. Here's the full code with some other refactoring:

```
private static void InsertData<T>(string[,] matrix)
{
    // Just add dummy data while testing
    matrix[0, 0] = "1";
    matrix[0, 1] = "FirstName";
    matrix[0, 2] = "LastName";
    matrix[0, 3] = "123 Main St";
    matrix[0, 4] = "98765";
    matrix[0, 5] = "(123) 456-7890";
    matrix[0, 6] = "user@provider.com";
    return;

    matrix[0, matrix.GetLowerBound(1)] = "1";

    for (var j = 1; j < matrix.GetLength(1); j++)
    {
        do
        {
            Console.Write($"\nInsert {GetHeader<T>(j)}: ");
            matrix[0, j] = Console.ReadLine();
        } while (string.IsNullOrEmpty(matrix[0, j]));
    }
}

private static void ListData<T>(string[,] matrix)
{
    var array = new string[matrix.GetUpperBound(1)];

    for (var i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
    {
        array[i] = matrix[0, i];
    }

    PrintRow(array);
    PrintLine();
}

private static string GetHeader<T>(int i) => Enum.GetName(typeof(T), i);

private static void ShowHeader<T>(string[,] matrix)
{
    var array = new string[matrix.GetUpperBound(1)];

    for (var i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
    {
        array[i] = GetHeader<T>(i);
    }

    PrintLine();
    PrintRow(array);
    PrintLine();
}

private static void PrintLine()
{
    Console.WriteLine(new string('-', Console.WindowWidth - 1));
}

private static void PrintRow(IReadOnlyCollection<string> columns)
{
    var width = (Console.WindowWidth - 1 - columns.Count) / columns.Count;
    var row = columns.Aggregate("|", (current, column) => current + AlignCentre(column, width) + "|");
    Console.WriteLine(row);
}

static string AlignCentre(string text, int width)
{
    text = text.Length > width ? text.Substring(0, width - 3) + "..." : text;

    return string.IsNullOrEmpty(text)
        ? new string(' ', width)
        : text.PadRight(width - (width - text.Length) / 2).PadLeft(width);
}

enum ClientHeader { Id, Name, Surname, Addres, CodPostal, Telephone, Email, State };

private static void Main()
{
    var client = new string[3, 7];
    InsertData<ClientHeader>(client);
    Console.Clear();
    ShowHeader<ClientHeader>(client);
    ListData<ClientHeader>(client);

    GetKeyFromUser("\nDone! Press any key to exit...");
}

private static ConsoleKeyInfo GetKeyFromUser(string prompt)
{
    Console.Write(prompt);
    var key = Console.ReadKey();
    Console.WriteLine();
    return key;
}
```

**Output**

[image]

Comment: yes, I get that this way it allows me to read the next line such as the Enum but what if I wanted to read an entire matrix with several lines, not just one such as the code above. How could I do that? I'm trying to apply to both codes I got but I haven't get there to read several lines...

Comment: You could wrap the code in an outer loop `for (int j = 0; j < array.GetUpperBound(0); j++) { // existing code here, except use `j` for the first index: array[i] = matrix[j, i]; }` I will try to update the sample later when I'm at my computer.

Answer (score 0):

I tried doing like this, don't know if it's what you meant, however the program crashes. Still doesn't read second line, I think the variable text from the method AlignCenter is null for some reason.

```
  private static void ListData<T>(string[,] matrix)
        {
            var array = new string[matrix.GetUpperBound(1)];
            for (int j = 0; j < array.GetUpperBound(0); j++)
            {
                for (var i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
                {
                    array[i] = matrix[j, i];
                }

                PrintRow(array);
                PrintLine();
            }
        }
```